# Is there a (cleaner) way to consolidate multiple conditions in C#?

Tags: c#

I am a beginner in C# and having trouble finding answers to simple questions. MSDN can be very cryptic for someone at my level, and I don't have a professional at my disposal for regular questions such as these.

This is an example of the code I'm working with:

```
while (ans != "a" || ans != "b" || ans != "c" || ans != "d");
```

Is there any way to clean this up?

Comment: You could put them in an array and check if your `ans` value is in the array.

Comment: are you sure you don't want `&&` there?

Comment: The simplest would be to extract the ugliness to a named method so it's more obvious what the point is of or'ing all those values.

Comment: As @Marc says, you probably meant `&&`-- right now, your statement simplifies to `while (true);`. If `ans` is `a`, the `ans!="a"` part will fail, but the other parts will succeed. This can be generalized for each term.

Comment: All of the answers below are the same as `while (ans != "a" && ans != "b" &&...` using && instead of ||.  As @Marc suggests, this is probably more in line with what you want, but it should be clarified.  Your current code would always be true.

Comment: Your current code is an infinite loop that will block the thread it's running in. Is that really “an example of the code I'm working with”?

Comment: To clarify: I didn't mean to use &&. This (while maybe not the most efficient method) was a practice in exception handling for a 'quiz' type console program. I needed something that continually evaluated if a valid answer was given (a, b, c, and d being valid answers).

Answer (score 4):

You can put these strings in a list and check if the answer is in the list

```
var list = new List<string>{"a", "b", "c", "d"};
while (!list.Contains(ans)) { ... }
```

The comment brought up a good point. Technically a set is better for this task because it can do lookups for membership very fast

```
var set = new HashSet<string>{"a", "b", "c", "d"};
while (!set.Contains(ans)) { ... }
```

Comment: Use a `HashSet<string>` for better contains performance :)

Comment: I think a comment that this is the equivalent of `&&` and not `||` might help boost this answer as its a very common boolean mistake to use `not or`

Answer (score 1):

Use hashset/dictionary for faster way of doing what you want, especially if list or strings is long:

```
var set = new HashSet<string>() {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
while (!set.ContainsKey(ans)) { ... }
```

Comment: Use a `HashSet<string>` for the same benefits but without the key-value overhead.

Comment: Dictionary doesn't really make sense here. Unless he was storing something with each letter.

Comment: Replaced Dictionary with HashSet as per popular demand.

Comment: I was hoping there existed something along the lines of:

    while (ans != "a", "b", "c", "d")

Your response was helpful and informative for more complicated problems though. I'll keep this solution in mind.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
    var characters= new HashSet<string>{"a", "b", "c", "d"};
    while (!characters.Contains(ans)) 
    { 
    }
```

Comment: This constructs a new list every time it is evaluated since OP was using a while loop it could be inefficient.

Comment: @TomDDD yes it could. There not enough info on context. Of course the list can be constructed once.

Answer (score 0):

"I needed something that continually evaluated if a valid answer was given (a, b, c, and d being valid answers)."

Sounds like to me that if the answer "f", or something that is not "a", "b", "c", or "d", is given you want the user to enter another answer.  If that is right then you do want && instead of ||.

I would just check the inputted answer against the characters 'a' - 'd' and not as a string.  This allows you to skip using Lists, HashSets, or Dictionaries.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1 + 2 = ?");
        Console.WriteLine("a: 1");
        Console.WriteLine("b: 2");
        Console.WriteLine("c: 3");
        Console.WriteLine("d: 4");

        Console.Write("Select answer: ");

        char ans;
        do
        {
            // Only accept the first character, using .ToLower to ignore casing
            ans = Console.ReadLine().ToLower()[0];
            if (ans < 'a' || 'd' < ans)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please select a, b, c, or d!");
            }
        } while (ans < 'a' || 'd' < ans); // This is your clean up


        Console.WriteLine(ans == 'c' ? "You are correct!" : "You are incorrect!");
    }
}
```

Results:

```
1 + 2 = ?
a: 1
b: 2
c: 3
d: 4
Select answer: l
Please select a, b, c, or d!
m
Please select a, b, c, or d!
o
Please select a, b, c, or d!
c
You are correct!
```

See working example here ... https://dotnetfiddle.net/us7D3K

Answer (score -1):

As a warning all of these answers are sacrificing performance for "cleaner code". These answers all have to allocate memory then compare each value in the array with your variable which also has overhead (although using a set/dictionary on a larger set greatly reduces the overhead for lookups). **What you posted is going to be the most efficient way of doing this.**  However, if you choose to keep what you have the order in which you have those conditions can speed things up a tad. Since only one of those conditions needs to be false to fail you usually want to put them in the order of 'what is more likely to fail first'.

Comment: Depending on the context of the code, sacrificing performance in the name of cleaner code, *might* be the right answer. Cleaner code is more maintainable, which I would say is usually the correct choice.

Comment: I would usually tend to agree with you, but since we don't know the context of how or why this code is being used I thought this wouldn't be the correct assumption to make.  This is why I labeled it as a warning though.  Just some food for thought for him.

Comment: the OP is asking for cleaner code, not necessarily more performant

Comment: How do you know other answers are “sacrificing performance”? Have you benchmarked them? Hard-coded comparisons also must allocate memory, must compare values, and have “overhead”; look at the IL they create. How do you know the comparisons are a bottleneck that will have any effect on performance? The code he posted is an infinite loop with no side-effects; changing the comparison logic will have no effect on performance whatsoever no matter how long a comparison takes.